# 'Cannot read property navigate of undefined' for full screen Modal in React Native navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I'm trying to render a full screen modal in React Native when an 'Account' button is clicked in the top left of the header but receive the error

> Cannot read property navigate of undefined

Where am I going wrong with this?

AppNavigator.js file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Image,
  Modal,
  Pressable,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {HomeScreen} from '../../features/reports/screens/HomeScreen';
import {RiskAssessmentListScreen} from '../../features/reports/screens/RiskAssessmentListScreen';
import {ModalScreen} from '../../features/reports/screens/ModalScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = ({navigation}) => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="GoPAD"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyModal')}
        title="Account"
      />
            ),
            headerRight: () => (
              <Image
                style={{tintColor: 'blue'}}
                source={require('../../../assets/img/refreshIcon.png')}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Fire Risk Assessment - Flats"
          component={RiskAssessmentListScreen}
          options={{headerBackTitle: 'Back'}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

And my ModalScreen.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native'


export const ModalScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>This is a modal!</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Dismiss" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navigation` prop is only available in the children of `NavigationContainer`.

What you are doing right now is you are accessing the `navigation` at the parent of `NavigationContainer`, so `navigation` is undefined.

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. Move `NavigationContainer` up to your `App.js` or `index.js`, depending on your app structure.
2. Pass a `ref` to `NavigationContainer`, and reference the `ref` for its methods, [as shown in documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#ref).

Comment: Thanks, have moved it and will work with it that way, good to know though!